# A union may only be initialized with a value of the type of its first member,K&R

Tags: c, unions

I am learning K&R C.  In chapter 6.8 it states:

> A union may only be initialized with a value of the type of its first member; thus union `u` described above can only be initialized with an integer value.

... and defines a union u as follows:

```
union u_tag {
  int ival;
  float fval;
  char *sval;
} u;
```

I do not know how to understand this.  What does it mean, the initialization of `u` must be as:

```
u.ival = 323;
```

clearly, that is not the case , because I can initilize `u` as:

```
u.fval = 1.0;
```

or

```
u.sval = "hi";
```

What does Ritchie mean?

Comment: What your doing is assignment, try using an initialization list.

Comment: @H2CO3 yes,i tried,and the code complie ok.

Answer (score 10):

The posted code is performing *assignment*, not initialization. The author meant that the following is valid initialization as `323` is an `int` and the first member of `u_tag` is an `int`:

```
union u_tag u = { 323 }; /* Initializes u.ival. */
```

The following would be invalid as it would be attempting to initialize an `int` with a `char[]`:

```
union u_tag u = { "hi" };
```

However, since C99 this is no longer the case. In C99, designators were introduced:

```
union u_tag u = { .sval = "hi" };
```

In C89, if you wanted to initialize a `union` with a value intended for a member other than its first you could copy an existing `union`. This would particularly useful if you wanted to declare the `union` as `const`. For example:

```
union u_tag make_u_tag_with_fval(const float a_fval)
{
    union u_tag u;
    u.fval = a_fval;
    return u;
}

const union u_tag u_fval = make_u_tag_with_fval(1.0);
```

Comment: @jiych.guru, the only option pre-C99 is to initialize the first member of the union. If you want to use C99 then if gcc add `-std=c99` option.

Comment: guru, you'll need to look at your compiler options to see how to force it to use an older style of C if availabe.

Comment: @hmjd,i want to test it in my enviroment,so,is there any option of gcc or other way to simulate pre-C99?

Comment: @jiych.guru, don't compile with `-std=c99`.

Comment: i compile my code without `-std=c99` always,and i even compile it with `gcc -Wall -std=c89 a.c` and `gcc -Wall -ansi a.c`,both is ok,except some warnings.My gcc version is 4.2.4

Comment: @jiych.guru, the warnings will be the type conversions indicating that the first member, an `int`, is being initialised, even if you provide a `float` or `char*` value.

Comment: @hmjd but it should not only just warnings in C89,it should compile error,is it?when i wrote code like `union u_tag u= {"hi"};`

Comment: @jiych.guru, the warning will the same as `int i = "hi";` as that is exactly what will be happening. I treat all warnings as errors using `-Werror`.

Comment: GeeksForGeeks says that several members of a structure can be initalized at once but only first element of a union can be initialised https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-structure-union-c/ Can you guys please elaborate on this ? @hmjd